# writing to csv from cursor.fetchall() in python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

i am trying to write fetchall result to csv file using writerow, using sqlite3 package of python

```
import sqlite3
import time,csv
s=time.time()
con = sqlite3.connect("dreamtool.db")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from result3")
result = cur.fetchall()

c = csv.writer(open("temp.csv","wb"))
c.writerow(result)

e=time.time()

con.close()
print(e-s)
```

> i am getting error as a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```py
c = csv.writer(open("temp.csv","w"))
c.writerows(result)
```

To have the mode as `"wb"` means you want to write byte-level information, which is not what you have.

Comment: the data is being added to the right side of previous cell, is there any way to avoid that? writerow is writing whole data into single row

Comment: I've updated it to use `writerows`, missed the fact you're using `fetchall`, take a crack at it now

Comment: how can i add column names while creating csv file

Comment: have a single `c.writerow(listOfColumnNames)` before you call `c.writerows(result)`